# Continuity of a function defined by cases on a space obtained as an attachment of n-cell along another space

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, continuity, differential-topology

Reading "Morse Theory" by J.Milnor I found more than once this way of approach:

Let X and Y be two topological space. Suppose we want to define a continuous map from a space obtained by attaching a n-cell to X along a map $\phi: S^{n-1}\rightarrow X$. Let's call $X\sqcup_{\phi} D^{n}$ this space, $i:X\rightarrow X\sqcup D^{n}$ and $j:D^{n}\rightarrow  X\sqcup D^{n}$ the two inclusion maps and $\pi:X\sqcup D^{n}\rightarrow X\sqcup_{\phi} D^{n}$ the natural projection.  Additionally, suppose we know two continuous functions $f:X\rightarrow Y$ and $g:D^{n}\rightarrow Y$ such that the function $F:X\sqcup_{\phi} D^{n}\rightarrow Y$ defined by cases:

$F(\pi(i(x)))=f(x)$ if $x\in X$.

$F(\pi(j(x))=g(x)$ if $x\in D^{n}$

is well defined.

My problem concerns the proof of the continuity of the function:
The book doesn't say anything about how to prove the continuity of the function defined this way. I tried to give an answer by applying pasting lemma: if I show that both the sets in which we defined F are closed, it follow the desired result.  $\pi^{-1}\{\pi(i(x)): x\in X\}=\{(i(x)): x\in X\}\cup S^{n-1}$ is obviously a closed subspace of $X\sqcup D^{n}$, while I'm not able to say much about $\pi^{-1}\{\pi(j(x)):x\in D^{n}\}=j(D^{n})\cup i(\phi(S^{n-1}))$. If X is Hausdorff $\phi(S^{n-1})$ is closed in X and so $j(D^{n})\cup i(\phi(S^{n-1}))$ is closed in $X\sqcup D^{n}$ but in general I don't know how to prove it and in Milnor's book there aren't any hypothesis on X.

Can someone give me an hand? :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think there's something wrong with your equation $\pi^{-1}\{\pi(i(x)): x\in X\}=\{\pi(i(x)): x\in X\}\cup S^{n-1}$, it should be $\pi^{-1}\{\pi(i(x)): x\in X\}=\{i(x): x\in X\}\cup S^{n-1}$, right? And at least [according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CW_complex), a CW complex is always Hausdorff.

Comment: Thanks, I edited! The fact is that in Milnor's book the author is talking about a general topological space X(and so not necessarily a CW-complex) with a n-cell attached...I don't know if he just implicitly suggests that he has to be Hausdorff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're basically asking for the universal property of quotient spaces: If $f\colon A\sqcup B\rightarrow C$ is a continuous map with $f(a)=f(b)$ if $a\sim b$, then there is a continuous map $\tilde f\colon A\sqcup B\,/\!\sim\,\rightarrow C$.

To prove this, let $U\subseteq C$ be an open subset. By definition of the quotient topology, $\tilde f^{-1}(U)$ is open in $A\sqcup B\,/\!\sim$ if and only if $\bigcup \tilde f^{-1}(U)=(f|_A)^{-1}(U)\sqcup (f|_B)^{-1}(U)$ is open in $A\sqcup B$, which it is because $f$ is continuous.

In your case, $\bigcup \tilde f^{-1}(U) = \pi^{-1}(F^{-1}(U))=i(f^{-1}(U))\sqcup j(g^{-1}(U))$ is open because $i$ and $j$ are homeomorphisms when restricting the codomain to their corresponding image. In particular, they are open maps.

See also [“Proof of the universal property of the quotient topology”](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1697014/214724) and [“Adjunction space is a pushout”](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/27958/214724).